# How to add a dollar sign to handlebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I wish to automatically add a dollar sign ($) to any value in the template key field "total_of_new_installation" using handlebars.  How can this be done?

```
<li><span class="list-title">Total Cost:</span><br/><span class="list-value">{{total_of_new_installation}}</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

Total Cost: ${{total_of_new_installation}}

Comment: okay....it works....simple. but how can I place commas to say 10000...($10,000) @Qasim

Answer (score 0):

Use currency filter to display values in **$**

```js
 var bidApp = angular.module('biddingApp', []);

    bidApp.controller(
        'bidController',
        function ($scope, $filter) {

            $scope.$watch('bid', function (val) {

                $scope.result = $filter('currency')(val);

            }, true);
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;">
    <div ng-app="biddingApp" ng-controller="bidController">
        <p>
            <label>Enter a number</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="bid" />
        </p>

        <p> {{ result }} </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this use Handlebars registerHelpers. Please check this [https://jsfiddle.net/trilokvallamkonda/x0n753vy/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/trilokvallamkonda/bcjkg7du/11/) link.

```
<span class="list-title">Total Cost:</span><br/>
<span class="list-value">{{currency this.total_of_new_installation "$"}}</span>


Handlebars.registerHelper('currency', 
    function(input, currencySymbol, options) {
        return currencySymbol + input.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
)
```